# Coordinates to pixels

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

Let's say I have two geographical points $P_1=(512401.72N,0032120.17W)$ and $P_2=(512332.83N,0031948.64W)$. What would be the easiest way to scale line between the two so that it fit on a 800x800(pixel) interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/ is a better place for your question. Take into account that the answer depends not only on the mathematical length between those points, but also on types of hardware (different technologies represent pixels in different ways), human vision (sometimes the best looking line is not the set of pixels closest to the abstract line between them).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by interpreting the geographical points as points in 2D (which only works approximately for small areas). We let $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$. Note that West is considered as a negative direction (e.g. $y_1=-32120.17$). If you want $P_1$ to land on the point $(0,800)$ and  $P_2$ on the point $(800,0)$, then the following conversion is suitable:
$$
\phi(x,y)=\left(\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot 800 \ \ ,\ \ \frac{y-y_2}{y_1-y_2} \cdot 800\right)
$$
Note that depending on the relative position of your two points, this formula may need adaption. If you want a pixel output, you will also need to round the result to the nearest integer.